# Instantiating a class - No overload for method 'Subjects' takes '0' arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have referenced a dll in a asp.net 2.0 web site developed in Visual Studio. The person who supplied the dll said to reference it and instantiate a class called Subjects.

I have referenced it and if I type:

```
Subjects mySubjects = new Subjects();
```

it appears to be 'found' as 'Subjects' appears in light blue text.

If I then try to access a method by writing this:

```
string ProjectSubject = mySubjects.GetSubject(ProjectID);
```

again, it seems to be 'found' in that intellisense, as soon as you type the full stop after mySubjects shows the methods available to be called.

So far, so good. But, when I try to run the page, I get a compile error which is:

No overload for method 'Subjects' takes 0 arguments.

I don't understand. I thought you always had to reference a class with

```
someClass myClass = new someClass();
```

Comment: it looks like Subjects does not have a constructor with no parameters

Comment: Subjects if it takes no Params will yield this error message, this is the normal expected exception / error

Comment: It's possible that the constructor needs you to pass in parameters.  Normally, Intellisense would let you know this when typing your decleration.  Try right clicking on `Subjects` and choosing "Go to Decleration".

Comment: I don't see why the downvote folks. You should not display prejudice to one who is obviously new and inexperienced. If you can't handle newbie questions you should pretend to play the role of a teacher.

Comment: When you enter `Subjects mySubjects = new Subjects();`, put the cursor between the brackets and press Ctrl + Shift + Space and it should tell you what it expects as parameters. (VS2010 - not sure about other versions.)

Answer (score 3):

> No overload for method 'Subjects' takes 0 arguments.

This means that there is no parameterless constructor defined for `Subjects`. Intellisense should show you the possible options when you type the initial opening parenthesis, otherwise look up the class in object browser to see the possible constructors (there could be more than 1).

It is also possible that there is *no* public constructor defined on that class, however this is unlikely as the author has told you to "instantiate an instance of Subjects". Again, object browser should tell you what's available.

Comment: It's also possible that the only constructors are private/internal/protected, in which case you won't be able to construct one (explicitly) at all.

Comment: @Servy - true , i'll update the answer with that info. Although unlikely as the author has told the OP to instantiate it

Comment: If the constructor were private the error would be `Subject() is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the constructor for Subjects takes a parameter.

I obviously don't know if you have any sort of documentation for your assembly or not.

But you should be able to Visual Studio's 'Object Browser' feature to inspect the type, and from there perhaps figure out what type of parameter it takes.

Comment: In the Object Browser it shows:

    Subjects(nameofdll.Configuration);

Under Configuration it shows Api.key and Domain.